# Change the order of wrapping widgets helper for Flutter in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

On pressing <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> I see these helpers. Can I change their order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. They are calculated with a "smart algorithm" based on the context.

There is a feature request to place most used actions on top: [YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109130/Ability-to-mark-an-Intention-or-Inspection-as-the-preferred-acti).

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.